# Run specific datafixture + Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, path

I know you can run all datafixtures by running this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

And that you can run a specific fixture by running this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=/path/to/fixture1
```

But now I'm trying the second command to load a specific datafixture like this:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=/src/VolleyScout/VolleyScoutBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadRegionData
```

My LoadRegionData class is located at:

```
src/VolleyScout/VolleyScoutBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadRegionData.php
```

When I run the command I always get the following error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find any fixtures to load in:

- /src/VolleyScout/VolleyScoutBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadRegionData
```

LoadRegionData.php

```
<?php

namespace VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

use VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Regions;

class LoadRegionData implements FixtureInterface
{
    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $regions = ['West-Vlaanderen', 'Oost-Vlaanderen', 'Antwerpen', 'Vlaams-Brabant', 'Limburg', 'Vlaanderen'];

        foreach($regions as $r){
            $region = new Regions();
            $region->setRegionName($r);
            $region->setRegionDescription($r);
            $manager->persist($region);
            $manager->flush();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Just started Symfony a few days ago. Maybe I'm wrong. But, isn't it a better approach to `flush` the data once outside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=src/VolleyScout/VolleyScoutBundle/DataFixtures/ORM
```

Comment: error:  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find any fixtures to load in:

  - /src/VolleyScout/VolleyScoutBundle/DataFixtures/ORM

Comment: And wouldn't that load all the datafixtures and not one specific?

Comment: could you post `LoadRegionData` implementation  ?

Comment: update my answer path should not start with `/` sory it was a typo. I dont think you can load data for only one class. It is possible for a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the full path:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=/Users/foobar/projects/projectname/src/VolleyScout/VolleyScoutBundle/DataFixtures/ORM
```

Comment: With `doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle:^3.4.2` it's `--group=ClassName` or `--group=group-name` https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html#fixture-groups-only-executing-some-fixtures